# Convert Hebrew Letters into Equivalent Number

Tags: c#, hebrew

Other then hard coding this by hand I was wondering if there was a way that the.net framework would have this built in automaticaly, I know it can automatically convert hebrew dates into georgian dates but I need to convert hebrew numbers into georgian

IE   א
= 1
     ב
= 2

This goes into the hundreds. See [here](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/hebrew-numbers.html) for more info.

Comment: Do you mean "Gregorian" dates?  And perhaps "Arabic" numerals from Hebrew numbers?

Comment: NO I mean this http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/hebrew-numbers.html

Comment: @Jim was commenting on the title. "Georgian" doesn't really make sense. You are trying to convert "gemtriya" (each hebrew letter has a numeric value) into Arabic Numerals (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals - ie: numbers)

Answer (score 8):

Here is the approach that you should take:

1. Make `Dictionary<char,int`> that gives correspondence between each Hebrew letter and its numeric value
2. Parse the string one character at a time (best to do it right-to-left)
3. For each character, look up its value in the dictionary and add it to a running sum
4. Be sure to handle common scenarios for separating the hundreds-letters from the tens-letters (double-quotation mark) and separating the thousands-letters from the hundreds (single-quotation mark). For example, 5770 = ה'תש"ע.`. See the details in the link above for more on separations.

**Edit:** I just [published a GitHub Repo](https://github.com/yellis/Gematria) that exposes functionality for converting Hebrew text to numbers, and numbers to their Hebrew letter equivalents.